# JavaScript Как решить эту проблему: Uncaught TypeError: clock is not a function at <anonymous>:1:1

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня возникла ошибка, которую я не могу уже довольно долго решить. Испробовал всё, что смог найти, ничего не помогло. Прошу помочь в решении данной проблемы.

Проблема: Написал функцию для отображения даты и времени на сайте. Чтобы часы обновлялись, а не стояли на месте, я применил window.setInterval в window.onload, чтобы облегчить работу. В консоли выдаёт ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: clock is not a function at :1:1" - не видит функции clock() .

Что можно с этим сделать? (ошибки глаза мазолят)

`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <title>-------------</title>

        <link href="css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


        <script>
            window.onload = function clock(){
                window.setInterval(function(){

                //Часы:минуты:секунды
                    var date = new Date();
                    var hours = date.getHours();
                    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                    var seconds = date.getSeconds();

                    if(hours < 10)
                        hours = "0" + hours;
                    if(minutes < 10)
                        minutes = "0" + minutes;
                    if(seconds < 10)
                        seconds = "0" + seconds;

                // Дата и день недели   
                    var months=new Array(13);
                    months[1]="января";
                    months[2]="февраля";
                    months[3]="марта";
                    months[4]="апреля";
                    months[5]="мая";
                    months[6]="июня";
                    months[7]="июля";
                    months[8]="августа";
                    months[9]="сентября";
                    months[10]="октября";
                    months[11]="ноября";
                    months[12]="декабря";

                    var time=new Date();
                    var thismonth=months[time.getMonth() + 1];
                    var date=time.getDate();
                    var thisyear=time.getFullYear();
                    var day=time.getDay() + 1;

                    if (thisyear < 2000)
                    thisyear = thisyear + 1900;
                    if(day==1) DayofWeek = "Воскресенье.";
                    if(day==2) DayofWeek = "Понедельник.";
                    if(day==3) DayofWeek = "Вторник.";
                    if(day==4) DayofWeek = "Среда.";
                    if(day==5) DayofWeek = "Четверг.";
                    if(day==6) DayofWeek = "Пятница.";
                    if(day==7) DayofWeek = "Суббота.";

                    var str = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                    var str1 = "<center>"+ date + " " + thismonth + " " + thisyear + " "+ "года" + ","+" " + DayofWeek + "<\/center>";
                    var str2 = "--------------------------";
                    var str3 = "----------------------------";

                    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = str;
                    document.getElementById("my_date").innerHTML = str1;
                    document.getElementById("creation").innerHTML = str2;
                    document.getElementById("re_creation").innerHTML = str3;
                    setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
                }, 1000);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
            <div id="header" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                <h1>---- <em>|||</em><span id="clock" class="span-right-time"></span></h1>
                <h5><span id="creation"></span><span id="my_date" class="span-right-date"></span></h5>
                <h5><span id="re_creation"></span></h5>
            </div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ValeraStadnichenko Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.